# Proving if A for all x then B using contrapositive

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

I'm trying to prove a statement of the form $\forall x \, A \implies B$ aka if A is true for all $x$, then B must be true, using proof by contraposition. As far as I know, this involves proving the following statement:

$$\neg B \implies \neg \left(\forall x \, A \right),$$ which should be equivalent to

$$\neg B \implies \exists x \, \neg A.$$ However, this seems somewhat off to me. To me it looks like I just have to provide an example of $\neg A$, given that $\neg B$, but that doesn't seem right.

Another possibility was that maybe the universal quantifier shouldn't be "distributed", which would result in

$$\forall x \ \neg B \implies \neg A.$$

This can't be correct either, see below $^1$.

**What's the correct way to prove a statement like this using contraposition?**

---

As an example, the actual statement I'm trying to show is that if $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}=0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$. Also $^1$, it can't be the last form either, since clearly it isn't true for all $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Why does the second formula look "off" to you? In terms of your example, it says "if y is not zero, then there is some (non-zero) x for which the dot product of x and y is not zero" which is indeed the contrapositive - you do need to exclude x=0 however in your original statememt: "for all non-zero x, if the dot product of x and y is zero, then y is zero".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this seems somewhat off to me. To me it looks like I just have to provide an example of $\neg A$, given that $\neg B$, but that doesn't seem right.

Why doesn't it seem right?

Take, for example, the statement

> If all walls of this room are red, then this is a red room.

In this statement, $A$ is "wall $x$ is red", and $B$ is "this room is red".

then $\neg B\implies\exists x: \neg A$ is equivalent to the statement

> If this is not a red room, then it must have at least one wall which is not red.

which is sounds right, doesn't it?

---

Or, in your assertion, you are trying to prove that if $x\cdot y=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$, then $y=0$. Well, in this case, $A$ is "$\forall x: x\cdot y=0$, and $B$ is $y=0$.

The statement $\neg B\implies \exists x:\neg A$ is then

> If $y$ is not the zero vector, then there exists at least one vector $x$ such that $x\cdot y$ is not $0$.

This statement is indeed true, and easily shown by taking $x=y$.

Comment: It just seems odd to me that I can turn a problem of (roughly) showing something is true for all to showing it's true for some, even if it's with an implication. But your red wall example shed some light on this.

Comment: @imas145 You arent turning a problem from showing **something** is true for all to showing **it** is true for some. You are turning a problem from showing **something** is true for all to showing **something else** is true for some.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, what you have to prove is that $\neg B \implies \exists x \, \neg A$. So, consider the assertion, concerning $\mathbb R^n$,$$\forall x\,x.y=0\implies y=0.$$You wish to prove that if $y\neq0$, then there is some $y$ such that $x.y\neq0$. Indeed this is true: just take $y=x$, and you're done.